# white space between figures and tables

Tags: spacing, formatting

I have a figure and table placed next to each other the code but for some reason the spacing is way too large only on between theses two objects.

```
    \begin{table}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|} 
    \hline
    Measurement & Voltage \\ [0.5ex] 
    \hline\hline
    $V_m$ & 10V  \\
    $V_{o-ch1}$  & 10.1 V  \\
    $V_{o-ch2}$ & 10.1 V  \\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{\label{tab:table-name} Unmodified Full-Wave }
    \end{center}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.3]{Full wave waveform.jpg}
    \caption{Full wave: $V_m$, $V_o-Ch1$, and $V_o-Ch2$ }
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}

\begin{center}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=.1]{10 perc.jpg}
    \caption{10 \% Ripple Value}
    \label{fig}
\end{figure}
\end{center}

\begin{table}
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|} 
    \hline
     Measurement &  Theoretical Voltage(V) & Experimental Voltage(V) \\ [0.5ex] 
     \hline\hline
     $V_m$ & 10 & 10  \\
     $V_{o-Ch1}$  & 10 & 14.1  \\
     $V_{o-Ch2}$ & 10 & 13.2  \\
     Ripple & 1.0 & 1.0 \\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Table: 10 \% Ripple voltage 100 uF}
    \label{tab:table-name}
    \end{center}
\end{table} '''
```

Comment: if you only post a fragment we can't run it which makes it harder to answer. but placing `center` around `figure` is wrong, it adds vertical space at that point but the figure will typically float and appear somewhere else leaving the space around nothing. Normally you want `\centering` not `\begin{center}` inside the figure, again to avoid adding spurious space.

Comment: ...yeah, you use `\centering` inside the `figure`, but `\begin{center}`...`\end{center}` within the `table`. Use `\centering` in both.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You should *not* use the  `center`  envitonment with figures and tables, as it adds a spurious vertical spacing

Comment: note `[h]` prevents most floats being placed latex typically gives a warning and changes it to `[ht]`

Comment: so does \begin{center} go on the outside of the begin table cmd?